# Android multiple Id managing

Tags: android, button, for-loop

I've an Activity with two tabs. In the first one there's a `Button`. If this `Button` is pressed, a new `TableRow` is created in the second tab. This works fine.

Each `TableRow` has 3 views(an image, some text and a `button`). Each time a `Button` is created i assign an id to it (0,1,2...).

What I want is to set a certain text if the id is 0,1,2...whichever of that ids.

I've tried this but it's not working:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){

        case R.id.save:

            if (et.getText() !=null && thumbnail != null){

                 TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                 ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
                 TextView view2 = new TextView(this);
                 Button view3 = new Button(this);
                 view3.setOnClickListener(this);

                 titulo = new String[500];
                 mensaje = new String[500];
                 fotos = new Bitmap[500];

                 view.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                 view.setPadding(1, 5, 0, 0);
                 view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

                 titulo[i]=""+et.getText();
                 mensaje[i]=""+et1.getText();
                 fotos[i]=thumbnail;
                 i++;

                 view2.setText("" + et.getText()  + dateFormat.format(c.getTime()) );
                 view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                 view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                 view3.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                 view3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

                 tr.addView(view, metrics.widthPixels/3, 150);
                 tr.addView(view2, metrics.widthPixels/2, 100);
                 tr.addView(view3, metrics.widthPixels/6, 20);
                 tl.addView (tr, 0);


                 final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Tu entrada se cargó correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toastMensaje.show();

                    et.setText("");
                    et1.setText("");
                    i1.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }

            else{

                final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Tienes que añadir un título y una foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toastMensaje.show();

            }


        break;

        case R.id.photo:

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);


        break;

        case R.id.gallery:

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             startActivityForResult(intent, TFRequestCodes);

        break;

    }



        for (int j=0; j<titulo.length; j++){

            if (arg0.getId()==j){

            final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),titulo[j], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toastMensaje.show();

        }

    }








}
```

What is not working is this piece of code:

```
        for (int j=0; j<titulo.length; j++){

            if (arg0.getId()==j){

            final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),titulo[j], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toastMensaje.show();

        }

    }
```

And this is the XML file:

```
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#001521"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:hint="Lugar" 
                    android:gravity="top">
                    </EditText>

                 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="252dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:hint="Título"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine" ></EditText>

                 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#001521"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

               <Button
                    android:id="@+id/photo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:text="Photo" />

               <Button
                    android:id="@+id/gallery"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:text="Gallery" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/i1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Guardar entrada"
                     />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/tl"
                    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

                    </TableLayout>

                </ScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: what's the outcome that you're having ?

Comment: When i press the buttons nothing happens. Only the ones which i set the id's

Comment: did you try debugging ?, add this to your code `for (int j=0; j<titulo.length; j++){
Log.d("TAG","id = " + arg0.getId() + " j = " + j);
            if (arg0.getId()==j){
Log.d("TAG","its equal");
            final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),titulo[j], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toastMensaje.show();

        }`
and check your logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not initialize those in the onClick()

```
   titulo = new String[500];
                     mensaje = new String[500];
                     fotos = new Bitmap[500];
```

By doing so, everytime you click save , new objects are created and you wont be able to store your strings. Move them to onCreate().
Is i a global variable too?

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this here, istead of the comment :P

Try adding some logs to check if it's entering the loop

```
for (int j=0; j<titulo.length; j++)
{ 
 Log.d("TAG","id = " + arg0.getId() + " j = " + j); 
 if (arg0.getId()==j)
 { 
     Log.d("TAG","its equal"); 
     final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),titulo[j], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); toastMensaje.show(); 
 }
```

I'm suspecting your real problem is using `getApplicationContext()` instead of your activity's context. try this also.